# How do I solve the database lock issue on execution the query

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

hi friends can anyone tell me what is the issue with my query. when i execute, it lock the Database for 5 to 10 minutes, please help me to optimize this query .

```
SELECT 
    u.username, 
    u.email, 
    u.created_at, 
    p.firstname, 
    p.lastname, 
    p.address, 
    p.address_2, 
    p.city, 
    p.country, 
    p.state, 
    p.zip, 
    p.phone, 
    p.phone_2, 
    u.last_ip, 
    u.last_login_at, 
    u.auto_login, 
    u.registration_page,
    s.product_name
    FROM
    users AS u
        Left Join subscriptions AS s ON u.id = s.user_id
        Left Join profiles AS p ON u.id = p.user_id
    where u.registration_page='Chris_Cleanse' and
        u.id not in (select user_id from goal_sheets) and 
        u.id not in(select user_id from sheet_user_popup_not_adam) and 
        s.expired=TRUE ORDER BY u.id DESC;
```

Comment: This question is more suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you post the the otput of `EXPLAIN SELECT u.username, ...` (explain your-query)?

Comment: @D. Kasipovic  here is the output http://i.imgur.com/R1PYdeI.png

Comment: First of all, do `CREATE INDEX user_id ON subscriptions(user_id);` and see how does that reduce the time. Also you could replace two subqueries with JOINS and then add conditions WHERE goal_sheets.user_id IS NULL and sheet_user_popup_not_adam.user_id IS NULL.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: This is off-topic for Code Review.  This code doesn't appear to work, and we only review working code.

Comment: @Jamal As I understand it the code works, it's just too slow.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: Perhaps.  It was hard for me to tell from the explanation alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your subquery in where condition contains a plethora of datas.
Maybe You can try to optimize your SQL like below:

```
SELECT
    u.username,u.email
    FROM
    users AS u
        Left Join subscriptions AS s ON u.id = s.user_id
        Left Join profiles AS p ON u.id = p.user_id
    Left Join goal_sheets gs ON u.id = gs.user_id
    Left Join sheet_user_popup_not_adam sa ON u.id = sa.user_id
    where u.registration_page='Chris_Cleanse' 
        and gs. user_id is null 
    and sa.user_id is null 
        s.expired=TRUE ORDER BY u.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `INNER JOIN`. Visit [this page](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for a visual explanation of `JOIN`s.

**PS**: *Also escape the `` `table` `` and `` `columns` `` names properly in a query. It's good practice.*

**UPDATE**: Run an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` *(your query here instead of `SELECT ...`)* and analyze the results. Post them here too.

Comment: thanks CodeAngry for reply, i try it but it not work :(

Comment: almost 5 million records .

Comment: @haseeb :) Good one! Do you have indexes? Just adding indexes will take a while. It's good to have some more advanced MySQL know-how when you poke around with 5M rows and you JOIN them. And also consider moving to `DBA.SX.COM`.

Comment: @haseeb Add index on `registration_page` and `id` fields.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48846/discussion-between-haseeb-and-codeangry)

Answer (score 0):

You can try by making mysql view for above records, as there are about 5 million records